# Css issue in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I dont know what is the problem with magento.My whole site was working fine when I left my office at evening but next morning when I opened the site,the site was looking as if no css has been used.
It happened one more time that the site was not looking with proper css,but next day it was looking and working fine.

Now I am not able to understand whats going on with the magento,is something generating dynamically which is effecting my site.

I am having too much problem with this,,Can u pls give the solution for this.

Comment: Well, we would need more details than that. How about a link? What have you found out so far? Is your Internet connection working?

Answer (score 3):

@Priti Upadhyay we will need for you to provide us with some information regarding your site. At this time we have no access to your site, nor any of your code. This means that we have no way of being able to identify any symptoms or causes of your trouble.

If your site is not on a public address, you might want to open your site in the Google Chrome browser, and open the Web Developer tools ( right click on any location on your page, and click 'inspect element' ) and check your 'console'. The console can report errors that you may not be aware of otherwise.

For instance you may see that you have broken links to your css files. If this was the case, then you'd want to take a second to look at how you are referencing your css files in relation to your actual file hierarchy. If you are referencing css files incorrectly in your code ( /app/skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css ) when your file hierarchy may be something different ( /app/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css ).

Another thing to check for is that you've cleared your cache ( System->Cache Management ). This might not be the answer, but it's good to turn your cache off while developing, in case something gets cached as you're troubleshooting ( very annoying to forget this when caching doesn't reflect the current state of your code, and your code looks legit ).

Those are two things that I can think of doing. I can't really offer any more advice without a link to your site, or the code from what you're working on. It would be good to include the template file as well as the layout xml for the page you're working on.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can u pls chk this site and give me some solution.

Comment: @PritiUpadhyay you haven't provided a link to the site. I think what I'm trying to impart to you is this "Try to imagine that the people you are asking help from are _not_ able to see the code you are working with. Then try to imagine that the people you are asking help from have no Website to look at. Wouldn't you want to provide something to the people you are asking help from?"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, clear the Magento cache, and your browser cache (perhaps try a different browser).

If you have no success, are you using a CDN service such as Amazon CloudFront? You may need to 'invalidate' the CDN.

Other than that, you will need to provide a link.